# What are examples of official documents or speeches composed in verse?

Tags: political-history, literature

What are examples of official documents or speeches composed in verse? What is the most recent example of such document or speech?

One of the recent examples is Edmond Pope's attorney Pavel Astakhov who addressed the court in rhymed verse speech spanning 12 pages: http://www.kommersant.ru/doc/136839

I would like especially examples from politicians though.

Comment: +1 - interesting question. But perhaps define better what you mean by poetic form, particularly: Does free verse count?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about list

Comment: There is a problem with this question, and that is "Poetic form". The definitions of free verse differs in form very little from what since roman times have been seen as good rhetoric. The difference is normally that rhetoric is used to convince people, while free verse is used as an artistic expression. Hence, people have, post-facto, declared that some rhetoric is free verse. As such, what is poetry and what is not becomes a pure question of opinion, and this question therefore is not objectively asnwerable.

Comment: @Vector no, free verse does not count.

Comment: @Anixx - see my comments about the nature of poetry on my answer. You need to edit your question - you are not asking for things that take "poetic form" - your terminology is incorrect. Perhaps you are not a native English speaker and don't have exactly the correct terminology at your disposal. (Again, I am not campaigning for my answer - but a question should be accurately worded.)

Comment: @Anixx If free verse does not count, you should update your question to reflect that.

Comment: @LennartRegebro : "The difference is normally that rhetoric is used to convince people, while free verse is used as an artistic expression." If so the question is moot, since "official documents or speeches" are by definition not for artistic expression. So your logic has gone far afield while according to your premise, the invalidity of the question is staring you in the face.

Comment: @Anixx: I have edited the question to try and better meet site guidelines, which for example prohibit solicitation of lists. Please review to ensure that my edit maintains the proper spirit of your question, and re-edit or roll-back as necessary.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens The edit got approved, partly because one reviewer slipped with the mouse. http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/questions/699/how-do-i-rescind-an-edit-review I disagree with the edit and rolled it back. Although your edit got rid of asking for examples, you asked "how significant" something was, something that is impossible to answer. At least until we have a measurable standard for measuring significance. :-)

Comment: In Imperial China, official documents were "ideally" written in verse by the poetically-trained "mandarins" (although not all of them were). My father happens to be the nephew of this man http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liang_Shiyi who won high-level appointments after passing the national examinations (the Chinese version of the SATs) based on philosophy expressed in the form of poetry.

Answer (score 3):

Another example, more recent, is Churchill's [speech to the House of Commons on June 4, 1940](http://www.winstonchurchill.org/learn/speeches/speeches-of-winston-churchill/128-we-shall-fight-on-the-beaches), particularly the final paragraph though his rhythm and repetition occurs throughout the speech to a lesser degree. Again a fine example of free verse.

Churchill's speech served multiple purposes. Firstly it needed to inspire the British people to continue the war. Secondly it needed to send a firm message to Hitler and Roosevelt that Britain was continuing the fight even without France. Thirdly it was part of a campaign by Churchill to obtain 50 moth-balled destroyers from the US that were needed for convoy escort. To that end it was vial that the US believe that Britain would continue the fight *to the bitter end*, and that the us would not be releasing the vessels only to have them attacking US commerce soon after. It would appear that the speech achieved all three objectives admirably.

Looking further back, one is left to wonder if all of Henry V's [St. Crispins' Day address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St_Crispin%27s_Day_Speech) to his troops was wholly Shakespeare, or if any was possibly original Henry.

**Update** from [Wikipedia on **Prose**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prose):

> On this point [distinction of prose from poetry] Samuel Taylor Coleridge requested, jokingly, that
>   novice poets should know the "definitions of prose and poetry; that
>   is,
>     prose,—words in their best order;
>     poetry,—the best words in their
>   best order."

**Update #2**:
I just remembered MLK's [I Have a Dream](http://historywired.si.edu/detail.cfm?ID=501) speech, particularly the second half. This speech was a seminal moment in the Civil Rights movement of the 1960's. An estimated one million attendees, white as well as black, attended in the Washington summer heat expecting the performance of a lifetime from King, and he delivered. I find it easy to imagine that any unsatisfactory performance by King on this occasion might have set the civil rights movement back, by disheartening the grass-roots support that it so depended on. Instead, King delivered probably his finest speech, to his largest audience.

Comment: I agree that the final verse of that speech can be regarded as poetry. It is also written after free verse became an accepted form of poetry, instead of predating it. The rest of the speech is not, it's just a fine example of rhetoric. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetoric

Comment: Sorry, I am not interested in "free verse". I am interested in true poetry.

Comment: The Henry's speech would count if it was not from a play by a poet, lol.

Comment: @Anixx - LOL. But Shakespeare used blank verse - "unrhymed iambic pentameter". Does this meet the definition of poetry according to your standards?

Comment: @Vector following the link I see rhymed poetry to my impression. Anyway, it would count.

Comment: @Annix - "As you like it" :-)

Comment: @LennartRegebro :"It is also written after free verse became an accepted form of poetry, instead of predating it." When exactly was that? Let's have the timeline... And as explained, rhetoric and poetry are NOT mutually exclusive by any means.

Comment: @Anixx: Do you not think that 15th century Kings had speechwriters, just as Kings and Presidents have today? I would propose that most speechwriters of 500 years ago were better versed (sic) in both rhetoric and poetry than most today.

Answer (score 1):

Although perhaps not the most recent, it may well be the most famous: **Lincoln's Gettysburg Address** is considered to be one of the finest examples of free verse in the English language. 
See: [The Gettysburg Address is poetry....Here is a list of the stylistic techniques and principal messages of the Address,](http://www.ohio.com/blogs/akron-law-cafe/akron-law-caf%C3%A9-1.295890/lincoln-the-gettysburg-address-1.296040) for some very interesting discussion and analysis, as well as more scholarly references. I quote a short segement:

***Akron Law Café 
Lincoln:  The Gettysburg Address, 
By Wilson Huhn, Published: February 10, 2009:***

> ...The Gettysburg Address is poetry.  It is one of the finest examples of
>   free verse in the English language.  Lincoln voraciously read and
>   enthusiastically watched Shakespearean plays, and this speech
>   approaches Shakespeare at his best.  The message is also important and
>   powerful.  It seeks to persuade us that America is a wonderful country
>   not because of its wealth or its armies or its fruitful land or even
>   its people (or, as many people of the South believed, because of White
>   Supremacy), but because of the enduring principles to which we are
>   devoted.  Here is a list of the stylistic techniques and principal
>   messages of the Address *(redacted by me to include only those related to poetry per se)*: ***Rythym; Repetition; Metaphor; ..***

**Henry Louis Mencken, 1920, on the Gettysburg Address:**

> It is genuinely stupendous. But let us not forget that it is **poetry**,
>   not logic; beauty, not sense.

Comment: @LennartRegebro - I guess you didn't bother to read answer's citation (it's not mine) which clearly outlines characteristics which define POETRY. And although you are not an a native English speaker (AFAIK) you are contradicted by numerous English speaking scholars, as a quick search on "gettysburg address" and "poetry" shows. And then we have this: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/poetry?s=t: "the art of rhythmical composition, written or spoken, for exciting pleasure by beautiful, imaginative, or elevated thoughts." BTW, poetry and rhetoric are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: @LennartRegebro - poetry does not have to rhyme... and according to your definition you should also downvote the other answer.

Comment: @LennartRegebro - Henry Louis Mencken, 1920, on the Gettysburg Address:
"It is genuinely stupendous. But let us not forget that it is poetry, not logic; beauty, not sense."

Comment: Sorry, I am not interested in "free verse". I am interested in true poetry.

Comment: @Anixx - you know what you are looking for. But did not make the mistake of believing that blank verse is not "true poetry" - John Milton and to some extent William Shakespeare, two of greatest POETS of the English language, used "blank verse", not to mention **HOMER**. Poetry does not mean just something that rhymes. See http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/poetry?s=t "Poetry -"the art of rhythmical composition, written or spoken..." poetry is defined by rhythmic composition with a musical sort cadence..." and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poetry for an extensive discussion.

Comment: @Anixx - Many poets and scholars consider rhymes a primitive, quaint constrain that detracts from poetry by forcing the poet to limit his expression to the constraints of formalized patterns. Claiming that "blank verse" is not poetry is akin to claiming jazz is not music. See also dictionary.com-"blank verse": "unrhymed verse, especially the unrhymed iambic pentameter most frequently used in English dramatic, epic, and reflective verse." "unrhymed iambic pentameter" was Shakespeare's (**The Bard**) preferred form. (not campaigning for my answer - just some information about "true poetry")

Comment: @Vector free verse in not just something without rhyme. It is something without meter as well. I do not know about Homer writing something without meter.

Comment: @Anixx: I agree:  There is a distinction between "free verse" and "blank verse" which I glossed over, along the lines you explained. However "free verse" is also considered poetry. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_verse: "Free verse is an open form (see Poetry analysis) **of poetry**. It does not use consistent meter patterns, rhyme, or any other musical pattern. **It thus tends to follow the rhythm of natural speech**." Since it involves the conscious use of rhythm, it qualifies as poetry: artistic use of language with a musical, rhythmic quality. Not sure where the GAddress falls...

Comment: @vector: +1 from me at any rate. I cannot think of a finer example than the G. A. of what OP is looking for (including mine).

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - I had given you +1 because even though I don't know that speech, I love Churchill, so we're even. Not sure what the OP is looking for....